# How to patch anonymous functions?

Tags: javascript, webpack, monkeypatching, browser-extension

I want to develop a browser extension that should modify a function, like monkey-patch. The problem is that the site is build by an assembly tool, like webpack, so there is no access to the desired function from the global scope. Is it possible to patch in this case?

Comment: As the functions are inside a closure I don't think they can be monkey-patched, but I'd love to be wrong.